# Do different browsers handle initial page load time differently?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer

My webpage initial loads time is less than 2 seconds in firefox, Safari and Opera. But the same page takes 29 seconds to load in IE7/IE8. Do browsers handle initial time differently? How do I optimize the page load time for IE browsers?

Attaching the webpagetest image which shows the high initial load time in IE.[image: Initial page load time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many factors comprising page load speed. I suspect there could be two things making this bad for IE here:

- The javascript engine in IE <= 8 is *way* slower than anything else
- IE used to limit parallel downloads to 2 per host, so you're download those ~2mb of images in sequence

Is this a public webpage? You should work reducing the size of your assets, everything (HTML/CSS/JS/Images) is huge. Pages should seldomly go over 600kb as a whole, downards of 300kb is ideal.

Comment: On a 2Mbps connection, it would take a minimum of 8 seconds to view the page. Slow...